# call function inside a closure js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm using EcmaScript 6 class here is my code :

```
           getFiles(callback) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: this.app.url('file/get'),
                  type: 'GET',
                  data: {},
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                  callback(data); 
                });

           }

           insertFiles(callback) {
               let that = this;

               that.getFiles(function (data) {

                  that.fileHolder.html(data);
                  callback(data);
               }.bind(that));
           }
```

and my errro is : callback is not a function, the error refers to the callback that is inside `insertdFiles()` method , `getFiles()` method works fine, so why am I getting the error? it seems that `getFiles()` has almost the same code and it works but the `insertdFiles()` throws this error, please help, how can I solve it ? Thank You

Comment: from the looks of it, the `insertFiles` is called with something other than a function

Comment: show us how you call insterFiles

Comment: Don't use callbacks, use promises. (Your code doesn't even allow handling any errors). Also, you don't need to `bind` a function that doesn't use `this`.